# Securing specific fields of a record in Google App Maker

Tags: security, google-app-maker

I am building an app in Google App Maker and I am wondering how I can secure specific fields of a record to only make them visible to specific users / roles. Let's say for example that I have an Employee table containing the employee's name, surname, email and salary. I want all users to be able to see the name, surname and email but only admins to be able to see the employee salary. I can use the user roles to secure the UI, however my problem is that even when the employee salary does not appear in the UI it is still fetched from the server, therefore someone could still access it if they were determined enough (ex. by observing requests / responses).
Is there a way to secure specific fields of a relation based on user roles?

Comment: Very interesting. If you are so worried about it, I'd recommend to use calculated models and control if the salary info will be available depending on the user role.

Comment: @Morfinismo Thanks for the suggestion, I'll probably try it out if I don't find any other alternatives. It just feels weird not having a way to do this "out of the box" given all the different way Google have written in their documentation that UI security is not enough and you should always secure your datasources as well (which makes sense of course).

Comment: Untested, however you might consider setting up the salary information in a related table and then setting the Load security level of the salary table to your specific user roles. As stated this is untested, however I think it might work.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa I thought about this but it lacks in flexibility a bit. If I decide that I want to change which role sees what down the line I'll have to move fields between different tables and I'm afraid this will get complex soon...

Comment: Indeed what you are describing could become complex. Let me ask why or how you might change roles as to what content they can see? Maybe that way we can better suggest other options. What @Morfinismo suggested may very well work for you, however keep in mind that calculated models may not offer the flexibility you are wanting either depending on the complexity of things.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa To tell you the truth I don't have specific use cases in mind which is why I would appreciate to have the flexibility to easily change who sees what. In reality I would have more fields that I need to hide, not just the salary, and 3 - 4 different roles who might need to see different field combinations so with that in mind I'm thinking that I very well might need to change a bit who sees what in the future.

Comment: @Morfinismo After a bit of searching and experimenting it seems I'm going to use the calculated models solution after all so if you want to post that as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using calculated model (based on a server side script) is the best option here. That way, only the data that you need to show will be fetched. So in your case, as an example we can use a calculated model called **EmployeeInfo** with the fields **name** and **salary**. The Server Script of that datasource can contain something like this:

```
return getEmployeeInfo();
```

Then on your server script you can have something like this:

```
function getEmployeeInfo(){
  var userRoles = app.getActiveUserRoles(); 
  var query = app.models.Employees.newQuery();
  var allEmployees = query.run();

  var allRecs = [];
  for(var i=0; i<allEmployees.length; i++){
    var empInfo = app.models.EmployeeInfo.newRecord();
    var employee = allEmployees[i];
    empInfo.name = employee.name;
    if(userRoles.indexOf("Admins") > -1){
      empInfo.salary = employee.salary;
    }
    allRecs.push(userInfo);
  }
  return allRecs;
}
```

That way you control if the salary will be returned only if it is an admin.